# How to access python bool variable from C code?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have been working on extending a Python application using ctypes to call a shared library in C code. I have a boolean variable in Python which I would like to check periodically in an infinite loop in the C code to see if it changes. Is there a way to send the memory address of the python variable to the C function and access the content?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a reference to an actual Python `bool`. But you could make a `ctypes.c_bool`, pass a pointer to it to your C code, and then have Python code assign it's `.value` attribute to change the value from C's point of view.

```
from ctypes import *

# Flag initially false by default, can pass True to change initial value
cflag = c_bool()  

# Call your C level function, passing a pointer to c_bool's internal storage
some_c_func(byref(cflag))

# ... other stuff ...

# If C code dereferences the bool* it received, will now see it as true
cflag.value = True
```

Comment: I tried this but the C code is not able to "see" the change that the Python code performed on the variable.

Comment: @EduMoga: How is the C code declared? If it's not declaring the argument as a `volatile bool*` (perhaps some sort of atomic), the optimizer could easily be caching the value from memory to a register once and never rereading the memory (I'm assuming threads are involved here, since otherwise the infinite loop in C would never return to Python, so Python would never get a chance to change the `bool`).

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the issue using a multiprocessing.Value object to use the c_bool in order to be able to access it from C code and be able to see the change reflected. The original question did not include the multiprocess/multithread issue so I marked the answer as correct.